# Parsing JSON output from Perl Script in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a PHP file that runs a Perl script, using popen and the perl script outputs the following back to the php

```
{ 'City' => [ 'LA', 'Chicago', 'NY' ], 'Name' => 'Kevin Bridges', 'Id' => '7075', 'Last-Status-Change' => { 'Time' => 14172911, 'User' => 'kbridge', 'To' => 'LAX', 'From' => 'ORD' }}
```

I cannot modify the perl script, and I really don't know the contents of it. But it looks like it is outputting JSON. I have tried using json_encode to grab the contents of the output but no success. Can anyone tell me if it is possible to parse this or do I have to manually write a parser?

Comment: That is not json, the single quotes and `=>` will not work in json. You could replace the single quotes with double ones and the `=>` with a `:` but that's a hack that is bound to fail at some point.

Comment: Would you consider just parsing it manually to be the best option then?

Comment: It depends how fixed your data format is. If there are never any double quotes or `=>` sequences in the data you could replace and parse the result as json.

Answer (score 1):

Convert `=>` to `:` and `'` to `"`. After that use `json_decode` to create associative array from the string.

```
$array = json_decode(str_replace(["=>", "'"], [":", '"'], $a), true);
```

Comment: I was able to successfully replace all of the `=>` to `:` and `'` to `"`. But when I do `var_dump(json_decode($output, true));` I get NULL and thats it.

Comment: I tested this code with your input in `$a`, and it works. Make sure you are not using `json_decode` twice. Also that you have JSON extention enabled on your server.

Comment: Also make sure your Perl script output don't have any more inconsistency with JSON then `=>` and `'`.

Comment: Really weird my code looks like this:
`$read = "{ 'City' => [ 'LA', 'Chicago', 'NY' ], 'Name' => 'Kevin Bridges', 'Id' => '7075', 'Last-Status-Change' => { 'Time' => 14172911, 'User' => 'kbridge', 'To' => 'LAX', 'From' => 'ORD' }}";`

`var_dump(json_decode(str_replace(["=>", "'"], [":", '"'], $read), true));`I checked the json.ini file and nothing is commented out

Comment: It works! Now, try looking for any php errors reported. You can see errors by inserting `ini_set('display_errors','On');error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of your script.

Comment: Hmmm thank you for the help. This is really weird. My php script consist of the two error lines you gave me. As well as the two lines I provided before. However, when I refresh the page I see absolutely nothing now. Do you have any idea what could be wrong ?

Comment: Is your page loading correctly? I mean with status 200. Or is it 500(Internal Server Error) or anything else. It may happen if you have some syntax error(like missing semicolon or bracket), or if your server is misconfigured somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

That's not JSON but is "almost" the PHP `[]` array syntax, except it uses some `{}`.  You could try:

```
eval('$array = ' . str_replace(['{','}'], ['[',']'], $output) . ';');
print_r($array);
```

Comment: That's even worse than my hack ;-)

Comment: Ha! No.  I go from PERL something to PHP array.  Yours goes from PERL to JSON to PHP ;-)

Comment: Perhaps, but that `eval` on the results of an unknown perl script looks pretty scary to me :)

Answer (score 0):

It does not looks like to be a valid JSON, it seems to be a PERL hash, so i think you gonna need to parse that manually... a simple way to you accomplish that in PHP, it would be to replace the {-} to [] and you can eval that string to be consider an array in PHP